# Using threads into Perl object oriented package

Tags: multithreading, perl, oop

I have this test script:

```
use threads;

start();

sub start {
  my $A = threads->create(\&A);
  my $B = threads->create(\&B);
  sleep;
}

sub A {
  while (1) {
    print "A\n";
    sleep(1);
  }
}

sub B {
  while (1) {
    print "B\n";
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

The output for this would be (once a second, forever):

```
A
B
```

I'm trying to do the same with an object oriented package:

```
package Test;
use threads;

sub new { my ($class) = @_;
  my $self = {
    A => undef,
    B => undef
  };
  bless $self, $class;
  return $self;
}

sub start { my ($self) = @_;
  $self->{A} = threads->create(\&{$self->A});
  $self->{B} = threads->create(\&{$self->B});
  sleep;
}

sub A { my ($self) = @_;
  while (1) {
    print "A\n";
    sleep(1);
  }
}

sub B { my ($self) = @_;
  while (1) {
    print "B\n";
    sleep(1);
  }
}

1;
```

And then:

```
use Test;

my $test = Test->new();

$test->start();
```

The output for this would be (once a second, forever):

```
A
```

It seems like the code gets stuck on the first thread.  I'm having a hard time understanding the logic behind threads in Perl. How can I replicate the same behavior from the first script in an object oriented package?

Comment: The `start` routine in the first example should use invoke `join` on each thread instead of sleeping forever.

Comment: I agree.  I used `sleep` because I had to type less =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$self->A` is a method call that never returns, so `\&{$self->A}` also never returns, and you never get to define `$self->{B}`.

One way to do it would be

```
$self->{A} = threads->create( sub { $self->A } );
$self->{B} = threads->create( sub { $self->B } );
```

The expression `sub { $self->A }` defines an (anonymous) subroutine and passes it to the `threads::create` method, but does not call the subroutine, allowing the program to proceed.

Comment: Thank you.  That was the problem.  I tried `$self->{A} = threads->create(\&A, $self);`.  That seems to work too.

Comment: The problem with `threads->create(\&A, $self)` is that the sub `A` does not get "called as a method". This means that subclasses of your class `Test` will not be able to override the method. Use `threads->create(sub { $self->A })` as per @mob's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more interesting test script.

You should invoke the methods on the instance of the object by closing over the instance in an anonymous subroutine.

I don't know what you wish to achieve with `threads->create{\&{$self->A}};`

Before `create` can be invoked, the invocation `$self->A` must return a value. But, it is designed to never return. But, then, you also have curly brackets in what is supposed to be your `create` invocation. So, that's confusing, to say the least.

Also, please don't try to save lines by sacrificing the readability of your code.

```
package Test;
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless { A => undef, B => undef } => $class;
}

sub start {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{$_} = threads->create(sub { $self->$_ }) for qw(A B);
    $self->{$_}->join for qw(A B);
    return;
}

sub A {
    my $i = 'A';
    while (10 > time - $^T) {
        print "$i\n";
        $i++;
        sleep 1;
    }
}

sub B {
    my $i = '0';
    while (10 > time - $^T) {
        print "$i\n";
        $i++;
        sleep 1;
    }
}

package Main;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = Test->new;
$test->start;
```

Comment: I'm working on a robot which runs forever downloading information from 6 different processes.  It already works, but I'd like to make it work as an object so I can use multiple instances of the robot if necessary.  About the curly brackets, it was a typo; about the legibility... I guess that's about the way I read parameters, is that right?

Comment: When you write `sub start { my ($self) = @_;`, it is very easy to miss the assignment to `$self` &hellip; at least I did.